# Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit'

Tags: .net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, storage

I have this error on website today

Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. There is not enough space on the disk. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070070)

Comment: So have you checked that there is sufficient disk space?

Comment: Yesterday its working fine ,suddenly today morning error comes 
and there is enough disk space

Comment: Then clean up your hard disk drive or get a larger one. :-) You may also want to consider adding the tag ".NET" to your question.

Comment: Is this a question? To get better help, please state a question and describe what, if anything, you have already tried to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Message says: “There is not enough space on the disk.” Try to delete something from disk on which is your application.

Maybe, your IIS log filled up your disk. Try this to clean your IIS log: http://www.ehow.com/how_5171789_clean-iis-log.html

After you free some space on your disk, you should restart your application pool in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, delete the the data from the drive in which you have your application store. After that try to run the application again. Definitely your application will run.